# Fourier series exponential form

Tags: fourier-series

The Fourier series exponential form is

$$\sum_{k=-n}^n c_n e^{2\pi ikx}$$

Is

$e^{-2\pi ik} = 1$ and why

and why is $-e^{-\pi ik}$  equal to ${(-1)^{k+1}}$ and $e^{-\pi ik} = {(-1)^{k}}$, for this I can imagine for $k=0$ that both are equal but for $k>0$ I really don't get it.

And also could you also suggest or list what other primitives might be helpful in computing fourier series, which I was not able to mention here or haven't found out yet.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use Euler's formula.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo imaginary number i, i know for z=a+ib, b is the imaginary number but it is used like that as notation in our maths script

Comment: $c_n$??????????